# Populate a gridview on runtime

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I want to fill with data in some generic lists.
I used a "DataTable" as DataSource which has the columns I need (DataColumn).

```
GridView1.DataSource = CreateDataTable();
```

My problem is my gridview contains html tags so I need something like

```
myBoundedField.HtmlEncode = false;
```

and I need to change the caption of the columns and all this is not possible if I use "DataColumn". I found some code talking about BoundField. 
why/when should I use BoundField instead? what are the benefit?

Answer (score 2):

Create you `GridView Column` Objects and add them to `Gridview's Columns collection`. and you can create your own `ItemTemplates` for columns for your cuustom values just like you want to manipulate `HTML` here.

```
    GridView gvDynamicArticle = new GridView();

    gvDynamicArticle.Width = Unit.Pixel(700);

    gvDynamicArticle.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(0);
    gvDynamicArticle.Caption = "Report View";
    gvDynamicArticle.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    gvDynamicArticle.ShowFooter = true;

    TemplateField tf = null;

    tf = new TemplateField();

    tf.HeaderTemplate = new DynamicGridViewTextTemplate("ArticleID", DataControlRowType.Header);

    tf.ItemTemplate = new DynamicGridViewTextTemplate("ArticleID", DataControlRowType.DataRow);

    tf.FooterTemplate = new DynamicGridViewTextTemplate(DataControlRowType.Footer, ds.Tables[i].Rows.Count);              

  gvDynamicArticle.Columns.Add(tf);
```

follow these link for more information:

http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/168_Create_Dynamic_GridView_Control_in_C_ASPNet.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/dynamic_Columns_in_Grid.aspx

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1400-how-to-generate-gridview-columns-dynamically-based-on-user-selection.aspx

Add some bounded column and you can access data at `rowcreated` event and then use `server.htmlDeocde( <html encoded field value>)` to show in the grid.. in the same way you can save html code on row command with `HtmlEncode( <save html field value> )` using this event.

hope this help you..

Answer (score 1):

You can create columns for the grid dynamically using new Column() and assigning values to it.

Let me know if you want me to support it with a piece of code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ankit. Is there any type called Column? the problem is I have html content that I want to display in the cells. I create my datasource on memory by defining every single column using the type DataColumn

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, define your GridView as follows:

```
<asp:GriVview ... AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="Customer ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderText="Customer Name" />
    ...
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

(adapted from [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode.aspx))

It should be obvious to see how you can specify the column captions (`HeaderText`) as well as the HTML Encoding (`HtmlEncode`)  for each column. The `DataField` specifies the name of the column in your data tables.