# Add column to ASP.NET GridView at run time

Tags: asp.net

I need to add column to ASP.NET `GridView` at run time.  In the aspx file I have

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid" runat="server">
<Columns>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I need to add selected columns header and rows dynamically which are from Database.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110650/populate-a-gridview-on-runtime

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9112245/647884

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

Set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` in your `GridView` markup.  This automatically generates all the columns based on what exists in your datasource. Example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True"> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Or, in your code behind, you can edit the columns collection of your `GridView` using syntax like this:

```
myGrid.Columns.Add(myDataControlField);
```

Comment: @IndraRamasani No problem =)  If it helped, consider upvoting or accepting this answer.  For more info, see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)